# Approaching re-development

Tags: website-design, clients, business

Part of any new business is looking for new clients. I'm wondering if any of you guys approach old outdated websites for re-design? If so, how do you approach them without insulting them, or do you tend to steer clear of this method?

Comment: I'm not sure this falls into the scope of this website.

Comment: I've always thought that was a good idea. I wouldn't spend too much time per inquiry, and keep in mind many may have developed it themselves or had a relative, spouse, or other esteemed helper.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer said, keep in mind that they (or someone they know) may have been the original developer. If it's really outdated the owner probably thinks the site isn't worth the trouble...it probably isn't winning them any business, and never did which would explain why it's been left in poor shape. Convincing them that a properly built site can win them business will be an uphill battle at this point.